# Notepad++ REGEX find and replace second-last slash

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

I have a big textfile with multiple paths like the following examples. The paths are always different.
I'm looking for a regex (find and replace) in Notepad++ to replace the second-last "/" with "/;".

Example:

```
/testNAS/questions/ask/test/example/picture.png
```

After Replacing:

```
/testNAS/questions/ask/test/;example/picture.png
```

I tried with the regular expression `/(?=[^/]*$)` but this only marks the last slash.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?=[^/\v]*/[^/\v]*$)
```

Replace with `$0;`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3SorUr/2/).

*Details*

- `/` - a slash
- `(?=[^/\v]*/[^/\v]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more chars other than `/` and vertical whitespace, `/` and again zero or more chars other than `/` and vertical whitespace at the end of a line.

The `$0;` replacement pattern inserts the whole match value (`$0`) and then a `;` char in place of a match.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only, you could try following regex.

**find what**: `^(/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/)(.*)$`

**Replace with**: `$1;$2`

[Online Demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/KFCpE9/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^(                           ##Matching from starting of value in 1st capturing group.
  /[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/  ##Matching / followed by till next occurrence of / doing this 4 times total in here.
)                            ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
(.*)$                        ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has rest of the values here.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^.*/\K[^/\r\n]*/[^/\r\n]*$
```

- `.*/` Match the last occurrence of `/`
- `\K` Forget what is matched until so far
- `[^/\r\n]*/[^/\r\n]*` Backtrack to match one occurrence of `/` using a negated character class matching any char other than a forward slach or a newline
- `$` End of string

And replace with a semicolon and the full match using `;$0`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMzB4v/1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if you want to replace the fifth number slash, in your case the `second-last` from right to left..
Find what: `^(.*?\K/){5}`
Replace with: `/;`